# Orchard: How to force all the migration codes to run after I've deleted the App_Folder?

Tags: sql-server, migration, orchardcms

I'm learning how to create module in Orchard through a [Pluralsight video](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/adv-orchard). I got to a point where the instructior said that we could delete the whole App_Data folder to force Orchard to recreate a new and clean database.

Unfortunately, none of the migration methods are not run. So, I'm stack as I can't persist any custom data to the database.

How to force all the migration codes to run after I've deleted the App_Folder? I chose SQL Server CE.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you delete app_data, you'll have to go through setup again, which will eventually rebuild the database, if it's a SqlCE database. Is it? Because if it's a full Sql Server database, you also need to delete that database.

Comment: What usually works for me is to drop the table produced by the migration + to delete the entry for the module in table Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord. However, this is not 100% - right now I'm struggling with a migration which didn't restart after this. EDIT: it was because of an error in the migration, if there are none, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord table, it shows what version will be run next, so you can set the specific projects to the exact migration you need to run.